# Kotlin - Primary key constraint on id is ignored - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am using from `Architect Component` in my project ,and I have bellow `entities` for create a locale db and language of project is `kotlin`.

Result entity:

```
@Entity
data class Result (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id_result: Int = 1,
    @SerializedName("cohorts")
    @Expose
    var cohorts: List<Cohort>? = null
)
```

And Cohort entity:

```
@Entity
data class Cohort (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id_cohort: Int = 1,
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null,
    )
```

And CoursesList entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tblCoursesList")
data class CoursesList (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id_coursesList: Int = 1,
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    var status: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    @Embedded
    var result: Result? = null
    )
```

And here is my `converter`:

```
class CohortConverter {
    private val gson = Gson()
    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToSomeObjectList(data: String?): List<Cohort> {
        if (data == null) {
            return emptyList()
        }
        val listType =
            object : TypeToken<List<Cohort?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(data, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun someObjectListToString(someObjects: List<Cohort?>?): String {
        return gson.toJson(someObjects)
    }
}
```

But get me bellow error when I need to `Build` my project:

```
warning: Primary key constraint on id_result is ignored when being merged into CoursesList
```

Comment: Why are you embedding an existing table? You can use relation to refer that id to another table